# Changing the content of button using a style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I'm creating an application that contains two types of users; staff, admin. Each user has his/her own permissions. For example, an admin can add, edit, delete etc; while the staff can only view. Currently within my app, I use a `ListView` to display data and then use a `DataTemplate` where by I set my buttons within, as shown below.

[image]

However, I want to change the `content` of the edit `button` to show View, rather then edit if the user is a staff user. I tried implementing the following code, but it doesn't seem to change.

```
<Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding ShowEditCommand}" Width="50">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="View" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Role}">
                                    <DataTrigger.Value>
                                        <enum:EnumPermission>Admin</enum:EnumPermission>
                                    </DataTrigger.Value>
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Edit"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
```

I'm not very good with creating `styles` and therefore would appreciate some guidance in what I am doing wrong and what can be done to change it. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Originally, as pointed out, I forgot to remove the `Content="Edit" from the button. However, when I remove that, the style still doesn't fully work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Content="Edit"` from `Button` definition

```
<Button Content="Edit" ...
```

`Style.Trigger` will not be able to overwrite that value according to [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#listing). It's enough that you set default value in `Style` as

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="View" />
```

Comment: Hi, I only just noticed; updated my post. However, the problem still occurs. At the moment after removing the content, it just shows "View" rather then edit at all. Any idea why?

Comment: and if instead of setting `Content` to _View_ by default you do `<Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Role}" />`. Does it display _Admin_?

Answer (score 0):

first just FYI you should not change the content in the style , you can bind the content to a property and change that property value 
to solve this just remove Content="Edit"  from the first line